# Apache Airflow (2.0.0b1) - Create task dynamically and access kwargs in function

Tags: airflow

I'm using Apache-Airflow 2.0.0.0b1.  I have an EmailOperator that I'd like to dynamically change some of the arguments for.  Specifically, I wan to acccess the values found in `kwargs['ti']`

Below is my code

```
...
# [START get_email_operator]
def get_email_operator(**kwargs):
    export_file_path = kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(key='LUMA_TERMED_DRIVERS_OUTPUT_CSV')
    email_subject = 'Termed Drivers - ' + date_string
    return EmailOperator(
        task_id="get_email_operator",
        to=['somone@somwhere.net'],
        subject=email_subject,
        files=[export_file_path,],
        html_content='<br>',
        dag=dag)
...

print_date_op >> ... >> get_email_operator()
```

When this code is deployed to my Airflow system, it gives the following error.

```
File "/var/lib/airflow/airflow/dags/Luma Termed Drivers DAG/airflow_luma_termed_drivers_export_DAG.py", line 232, in get_email_operator
export_file_path = kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(key='LUMA_TERMED_DRIVERS_OUTPUT_CSV')

KeyError: 'ti'
```

How do I reference `kwargs` in a function that isn't a task, but that will return a task?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a python question, not an airflow one.  The function call doesn't fail immediately because `None` is a valid dictionary.  What you want though is to change the call to pass `ti=<something>` as a parameter to `get_email_operator` as in:

```
print_date_op >> ... >> get_email_operator(ti="something")
```

Though if you're going to do that the function reads more clearly as:

```
def get_email_operator(ti):
    export_file_path = ti.xcom_pull(key='LUMA_TERMED_DRIVERS_OUTPUT_CSV')
```